# Shell: Match exact string saved in variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have this file:

```
$ cat file.txt
/home/user/abc   test1   15-03-25
/home/user/abc   test2   15-03-25
/home/user   test3   15-03-25
/home/user   test4   15-03-25
```

and I need to match lines with exact path specified in variable (`$pathtosearch = /home/user`).
I tried basic awk command:

```
$ awk "$pathtosearch" file.txt
/home/user/abc   test1   15-03-25
/home/user/abc   test2   15-03-25
/home/user   test3   15-03-25
/home/user   test4   15-03-25
```

but it doesn't match exact string.

I need output to look like this:

```
$ command?? file.txt
/home/user   test3   15-03-25
/home/user   test4   15-03-25
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not substitute the variable directly into the awk code; it will be treated as code instead of data, and you'll run into problems with metacharacters (and open yourself to code injection vulnerabilities). Instead use `-v` to make the variable known to the awk code, and use an appropriate test to select the lines:

```
awk -v path="$pathtosearch" '$1 == path' file.txt
```

If the data is tab-separated (I have a hunch it might be), specify the field separator explicitly:

```
awk -F '\t' -v path="$pathtosearch" '$1 == path' file.txt
```

This will avoid problems with spaces in the search path.